# Nesting classes in order to imitate static members

Tags: python, api, class-design

I am trying to imitate "static" member by nesting a class inside another class in order to define the classes constants.

f.e.

```
class foo:
  class NoAuthActions: Action1, Action2, Action3 = ["action1", "action2", "action3"]
  class AuthActions: Action4, Action5, Action6 = ["action4", "action5", "action6"]
```

Is there a better way of achieving this in python?

I am doing this to achieve a better design for an API library.

**Edit:**

The API is a web requests based(google maps, foursquare, etc..) so I just need a better way to wrap it. Since the API it self is composed of types of actions that users can and cannot do without an oauth authentication I need a way to organize it better.

And so **namespacing** sounded like a better way to order things up, since there are actions for each endpoint in the requests api(it would be smarter to mention that I took this approach since all the actions have the same base url).

Briefly saying: I need a design that the API would be easy to use all the actions and make the authentication that's needed decoupled as much as possible from the API. After all, I only need an oauth token or an application_ID

**Thanks**

Comment: If you provided a real example, we could judge if it adds enough clarity to the name to justify the ugliness and boilerplate in the definition and the extra typing and reading for the API users. Generally, a static variable in other languages is the just a class level in Python. What you seem to want is an extra namespace for these constants.

Comment: @delnan I think I got it clearer now. take [foursquare endpoints api](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/index_docs.html) f.e., some of the endpoints require a real user authentication while the some require an application id

Comment: @delnan by the way this design is suited for the reason that the api is based solely on making requests each with different parameters and I need some way of making it neat. it's just like a static class members(the way I see it)

Answer (score 3):

Why the inner class?

```
class Foo:
    action1, action2, action3 = ["action1", "action2", "action3"]
```

will create a class `Foo` with three class attributes `action1`, `action2` and `action3`.  You can access them via `Foo.action1` or `foo.action1` for a `Foo` instance `foo`.  To change the value of a class variable, use

```
Foo.action1 = "new_action"
```

or

```
foo.__class__.action1 = "new_action"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the items to be read-only constants, consider using one of the answers to this question, [Class-level read-only properties in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735434/class-level-read-only-properties-in-python).