# Apply a function to all instances of a class

Tags: python, class

I am looking for a way to apply a function to all instances of a class. An example:

```
class my_class:

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.my_value = number
        self.double = number * 2

    @staticmethod
    def crunch_all():
        # pseudocode starts here
        for instances in my_class:
             instance.new_value = instance.my_value + 1
```

So the command `my_class.crunch_all()` should add a new attribute `new_value` to all existing instances. I am guessing I will have to use `@staticmethod` to make it a "global" function.

I know I could keep track of the instances that are being defined by adding something like `my_class.instances.append(number)` in `__init__` and then loop through `my_class.instances`,  but I had no luck so far with that either. Also I am wondering if something more generic exists. Is this even possible?

Comment: It should be a `@classmethod`, not a `@staticmethod`. And yes, you'll have to keep track of all of the instances of the class in a class attribute.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Register* objects with the class at initialisation (i.e. `__init__`) and define a *class method* (i.e. `@classmethod`) for the class:

```
class Foo(object):
    objs = []  # registrar

    def __init__(self, num):
        # register the new object with the class
        Foo.objs.append(self)
        self.my_value = num

    @classmethod 
    def crunch_all(cls):
        for obj in cls.objs:
            obj.new_value = obj.my_value + 1
```

example:

```
>>> a, b = Foo(5), Foo(7)
>>> Foo.crunch_all()
>>> a.new_value
6
>>> b.new_value
8
```

Comment: One extra thing to note is that in Python, this class variable is accessible by all instances. You can see that `id(Foo.objs)`, `id(a.objs)` and `id(b.objs)` all refer to the same thing. So if someone wanted to, they could do something nasty like `a.objs.append("hello")` and now `crunch_all` will have an error since that string at the end of `objs` doesn't have a `my_value` attribute to access.

Comment: Since this happens when the contents of `objs` is mutated (when it is reassigned entirely, the `__setattr__` sequence only happens for `a` and nobody else) you can improve this simply by making `objs` a `tuple` so that it can't be mutated, and then in the constructor, creating a new `tuple` out of the contents of the old one and the addition of the instance-being-created.

Comment: This is a useful related question: < http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735434/class-level-read-only-properties-in-python >.