# Dataclass prevents attribute from being changed

Tags: python, attributes, python-dataclasses, python-3.10

I am using python 3.10 So I have a python dataclass

```
@dataclass(frozen=True, slots=True)
class Card:
    COLORS = ["Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Blue"]
    CARD = ["3"]
    card: int
    color: int = None
```

So now if I create a object and try to change its attribute using `object.__setattr__` or `object.attribute = value` I get an error which is Ok.

But when I do

```
Card.CARD = ["2"]
```

It successfully runs without an error which I don't want I want it to throw an error

Like if I try:

```
>>> int.a = "9"
```

I get an TypeError.

```
TypeError: cannot set 'a' attribute of immutable type 'int'
```

What should I do so that when I do `Card.CARD = ["2"]` I get a error saying:

```
TypeError: cannot set 'CARD' attribute of immutable type 'Card'
```

Comment: `frozen` only applies to *instances* of `Card`, but `CARD` is  a *class* attribute. I don't think there's anything you can do with `dataclasses` to change that. Usually, you need a metaclass to enforce a read-only class attribute. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1735434/1126841, for example.

Comment: @chepner thanks for your answer